# Is it wrong to say "dovetails off" something?

Tags: prepositions

Can you say “dovetails off” something? Here’s the sentence:

> If you boil it down to that core objective, then everything else dovetails off of it.

I’m trying to figure out the correct preposition. Would it be correct to say “everything else dovetails with it?” Or are both of these okay to use?

Answer (score 1):

"To dovetail" is used idiomatically to mean "to connect intricately".
Every 'dovetail' connects *with* something (pin[s], slot, etc.), but "dovetails *off* ..." can be used when the mating part protrudes.